# What should be the path for storing Maildir e-mails?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email, postfix, maildir

Am I storing e-mails to the correct path?

Working from the [dovecot-postfix package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dovecot-postfix) I'm able to deliver e-mails to myself as so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
HELO me
250 dur.bounceme.net
mail from:<thufir@example.net>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<thufir@localhost>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
subject: to evolution mail

we'll see if this goes through.
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 43D6F2A07C1
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
thufir@dur:~$
```

and then here's the message:

```
thufir@dur:~$ ll Maildir/new/
total 20
drwx------ 2 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 16 18:56 ./
drwx------ 5 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 16 18:56 ../
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  410 Nov 16 11:57
1353095866.M305477P3932.dur,S=410,W=422
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  424 Nov 16 17:20
1353115248.M841336P2990.dur,S=424,W=436
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  445 Nov 16 18:56
1353121003.M187706P3838.dur,S=445,W=457
thufir@dur:~$
thufir@dur:~$ nl Maildir/new/1353121003.M187706P3838.dur\,S\=445\,W\=457
      1 Return-Path: <thufir@example.net>
      2 X-Original-To: thufir@localhost
      3 Delivered-To: thufir@localhost
      4 Received: from me (localhost [127.0.0.1])
      5     by dur.bounceme.net (Postfix) with SMTP id 43D6F2A07C1
      6     for <thufir@localhost>; Fri, 16 Nov 2012 18:55:55 -0800
(PST)
      7 subject: to evolution mail
      8 Message-Id: <20121117025613.43D6F2A07C1@dur.bounceme.net>
      9 Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 18:55:55 -0800 (PST)
     10 From: thufir@example.net

     11 we'll see if this goes through.
thufir@dur:~$
```

Do I perhaps have postfix misconfigured?  I ask because [evolution seems to use a different path for mail](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.evolution.general/45879).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really any such thing as "the correct path to store Maildir mail."  You store it wherever you want to store it.  You might choose to store it under users' homedirs, or you might choose to store it under an arbitrary path like /data/mail, or... whatever.